# UINavigationBar doesn’t display item parts in Playground

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift3, uinavigationbar, swift-playground

I’m playing around the UINavigationBar API in the Playground. The following code just results an empty navigation bar, without the title and back button.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let nav = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 342, height: 50))

nav.isTranslucent = false

let item = UINavigationItem(title: "Hello")
item.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Somewhere", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

nav.pushItem(ni, animated: false)
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work when you set the items array?

Comment: @dasdom No, doesn’t work either.

Comment: Did you set the navigationbar as the live view?

Comment: Thank you! `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = nav` did the trick. It seems not all views need this. Why it should be used here? I will look into that, but if you like you can make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I just postet an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. Have you tried to open the Live View? Have you set the liveView of the playground page?
[image]